# Insert data into database whose name is not known at execution time

Tags: sql, sql-server

As part of an application installer, I need to insert some data into an already existing database.  The structure of the database is known, however the exact name is not; i.e. I know the name of the table I need to insert into and its structure, but the db name is variable.

The db name's structure is: `AppDB_<version#>` (ex: `AppDB_V20_1_2`).  Unfortunately, when new major versions of this application are installed, the previous dbs are left on the server, so a query to:

```
SELECT name FROM master..sysdatabases WHERE name LIKE 'AppDB%'
```

returns multiple results.

Is it possible to create a query which inserts the same table across the entire range of results?

That is, if I have databases:

```
AppDB_V1
AppDB_V2
AppDB_V3
```

Can I write a query that effectively does:

```
INSERT INTO [AppDB_V1].[dbo].[TableName] ...
INSERT INTO [AppDB_V2].[dbo].[TableName] ...
INSERT INTO [AppDB_V3].[dbo].[TableName] ...
```

without knowing the number or names of the `AppDB`s beforehand?

Comment: You _could_ use something dumb like [`sp_foreachdb`](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/joew/archive/2008/08/27/60700.aspx), but I'd recommend having a consistent name for the current version of the database, e.g. (`AppDB`), and if you _absolutely_ need old versions (that's what backups are for, btw) then rename those with the version number.

Comment: @Dave Unfortunately, the database naming scheme is way out of my hands, because yeah that would be nicer for everyone.

Comment: Can you just make it a config value that is manually set before the application is installed? The other way would be to modify your installer or use InstallShield or something similar to have a place for the admin user doing  the install to input a DB name, from which you can build necessary conn string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dynamic sql to build you insert statement. Take a look at [sp_executesql](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx)

Query the db names. Then use a cursor to go though the database names and create a insert string. Then execute it with sp_executesql.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could generate a dynamic sql statement thus:

declare @sql mvarchar(max);

set @sql = N'';

select @sql = @sql + N', insert into ' + quotename(db.name) + N'.dbo.Table1 from dbo.SourceTable;' + char(13);

from sys.databases db

where db.name like ...

set @sql = stuff(@sql, 1, 1, N'');

exec (@sql);